# datatables - Pagelength event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Well, it do works but now how it is suppose to. Mean it gives me result after the second time i change page length. see the code below please. Here is how i have done it, but if there is any other better way please tell.

```
                $("#data-Tables").on( 'length.dt',   function () {
                    var tableHeight = document.getElementById('tblContainer').clientHeight;
//                tableHeight = tableHeight/2;
                    $('#theBody').css('height',tableHeight);
                }).dataTable();
```

what i want is when i change page length event should occur instantly after change of page length.

but here in my code/scenario, when i change page length from 10 to 25, the event is not fired, but when i change again from 25 to 10 it gives me previous result of 10-25?

when it responds late and give me old value of event change?

Comment: strip your handler function out of the call, give it a name, bind the event with the name instead of the anon, and also call the named function just after binding the event to execute it right away.

Comment: @dandavis
can you please show it in answer. sorry i can't figure out how to do it.